# How to defined a database connecting Flask python file and then import it?

Tags: flask, pymongo

1.I was trying to use Pymongo to connect to my MongoDB atlas database. I wrote this file into the connect.py file. Here is the tree folder structure. The connect.py contains the URL information to connect the database.

```
└── uploading
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── upload.cpython-38.pyc
    └── upload.py
    ├── Database
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── connect.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── connect.py
    ├── app.py
```

2.Here is code for connect.py

```
 import pymongo
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("URL",ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')
    db = client.datasets
```

Here is the code for uplod.py

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from Database.connect import db
sample = Blueprint('sample', __name__)

@sample.route('/')
def index():
    x = current_app.config['UPLOAD_PATH']
    return str(db)
```

Here is the code for app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'pj&\xe9\xd7\xd7\xabc\xe6KX\xbe\x9f<\x9f\x87'
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = 'public'  # to create a folder which is used to save the uploaded file
CORS(app)
app.register_blueprint(sample)
'''
Datasets and model upload
'''
@app.route('/connect-upload', methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def connect_upload():
    index=0
    # get username
    return "result"
```

When I tried to use : from Database.connect import db to import database in the upload.py, it showed error message :ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'Database.connect'. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing your module correctly. Your module should be the filename. You should use `from connect import db`.